# BlackBerry 10 C-ARES

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx, c-ares

I am writing an application that uses C-ARES to resolve DNS. The C-ARES library available with the system doesn't support **ares_parse_naptr_reply**, something that I really need. I tried to compile c-ares as an external library (version 1.9.1, which we use in other platforms such as Android and IOS), but it still doesn't work. I think that the compiler continues to include c-ares system headers first, something that I don't want.

When I run my application, I get this message:

**QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread**

and the following code error from C-ARES: **11 (ARES_ECONNREFUSED)**

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to fix this situation? Something to include in the compilation of this library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now solved! If you ever get this error, please check that ares_init has access to the resolv.conf file of the platform. that was my problem!